# How to configure beanstalkd to work with laravel Cache?

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd

I am trying to do some Cache operation inside an Event class which is a job processed by beanstalkd.

```
class NotificationListener implements ShouldQueue {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function handle() {
      //Handle notification stuff
    }

}
```

Then inside the handle function I am trying to store something in the laravel Cache:

```
  Cache::put("id", "123");
```

Unfortunately this throws following error:

```
file_put_contents(server_path/storage/framework/cache/data/18/60/18604da75750f7c9cd8eaf1a60b2210f8e4d4367): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at server_path/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:133)
```

I am using `file` driver for the Cache:

From Config.php:

```
'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],
```

I believe the issue is that beanstalkd is using trying to access Cache from a different path than laravel does. However, I am not sure how to configure that behavior.
The cache is working fine when used inside Controller and any other place that is not run by beanstalkd.

Laravel version: `"laravel/framework": "7.12.*"`

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry, that was me trying different solutions - it's using `storage_path`

Comment: what is the path before `framework` in that error?

Comment: ```/home/application_folder/```

Comment: so its missing the 'storage' part, have you restarted the queue workers since you have been making changes?

Comment: I did ```php arisan cache:clear``` then ```php artisan queue:restart```. The second command gives me the same error

Comment: I have double check the path, it's saying:


```
 file_put_contents(/home/application_folder/storage/framewor
  k/cache/data/ee/2f/ee2f842aa7bb1f53edf3a2ed2c09a1807ffa6c90): failed to ope
  n stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: alright, just making sure you know that the queue workers don't pick up code changes since they are already running processes

Comment: I could also make a workaround with ```Cache.lock()``` but that gives me another error:

```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Cache\FileStore::lock() {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Cache\\FileStore::lock() at /home/application_folder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php:646)
[stacktrace]```

Comment: lock wouldn't matter and doesn't exist for File cache ... what user are the queue workers running as?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: i have no idea how you are running your queue workers

Comment: From the application root folder I run ```php artisan queue:work --queue=queue_name```